# Mobile Web App, Jquery Mobile or Icenium or Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile, icenium

I have implemented a handy expense app with Jquery mobile, and it works well on Android, BB, Iphone. Jquery mobile is easy to use, open source, low learning curve..

I have also worked with bootstrap and it is wonderful. The only little issue is performance on some mobile platforms.

Recently, I have seen Icenium from Telerik, but I don't have any idea about it.

Does anyone know which one of these three solution does make sense for a mobile web application? Pros and Cons?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I've been working with Telerik AppBuilder for the past few weeks, and so far I've found it quite user friendly and powerful.

**PROS**: There are a lot of [sample apps](http://www.telerik.com/appbuilder/sample-apps) in the Telerik site to check for examples and source code, so you'll surely find something that can help you build prototype applications fast. If you're a Visual Studio user, you can greatly benefit from the VS Extension that lets you build apps using the VS IDE.

**CONS**: AppBuilder uses some native styles for different devices, so if you want to have a consistent design throughout many platforms you'll have to mess with some CSS to override the default styles. The greatest caveat is that if your app needs to show a lot of information in one view (like an endless scrolling view) the app may crash for lack of system memory, although there are workarounds to this. Also, if you need the Visual Studio Extension the monthly cost goes up considerably.

Since it has a 30-day free trial (which is also good for the VS Extension), I think you have nothing to lose by downloading it and see if it suits your needs.

Comment: FYI, Telerik AppBuilder doesn't use native styles - those are part of Kendo UI Mobile. Plus Kendo UI Mobile comes with a separate "flat" skin (that you can customize with the theme builder) and get a consistent UI across all devices.

Comment: Would you recommend using jquery mobile with Telerik AppBuilder? and if so is there any caveat?

Answer (score 0):

Icenium (now called Telerik AppBuilder) is set of cloud-based build services supported by three different IDEs (in-browser client, windows client, and Visual Studio extension). So you can use jQuery Mobile with Telerik AppBuilder, just like you can use any mobile JavaScript framework.

Comment: Can you please tell me what does that offer more than using jquery mobile alone?

Comment: jQuery Mobile gives you a mobile js framework to build your app. Telerik AppBuilder offers Kendo UI Mobile (which is similar to jQuery Mobile) but more importantly provides build services to create your iOS, Android, and (soon) Windows Phone 8 app binaries. AppBuilder also comes with a great device simulator and version control. (Disclaimer, I work for Telerik!)